# I have a proplem in c program that print the intersection of two input arrays

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

In this code two input arrays (a and b).It should print out the intersection between two arrays(common numbers) ,but it print first common number only.
For example a[1,2,3] and b[2,3,4] it prints in intersection array( I ) only 2 while it should be 2 and 3 .(the problem in code is determined by comment).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int n,z ;
printf("Enter size of array\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[n] ;
if(n<=20){
for(int i=0 ;i<n; i++){
    printf("Enter integer \n");
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
}
for(int i=0 ;i<n; i++){
    printf("%d " ,a[i]);
}
printf("\nEnter size of the 2nd array\n");
scanf("%d",&z);
int b[z] ;
if(z<=20){
for(int i=0 ;i<z; i++){
    printf("Enter integer \n");
    scanf("%d", &b[i]);
}
}
for(int i=0 ;i<z; i++){
    printf("%d " ,b[i]);
}
for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
    for(int j=i+1 ; j<n ; j++){
        if(a[i]==a[j]){
            for(int l = j; l < n; l++)
                {
                    a[l] = a[l + 1];
                }
                n--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
printf("\nArray1: ");
for(int i=0 ;i<n-1; i++){
    printf("%d, " ,a[i]);
}
printf("%d",b[n-1]);
for(int t=0 ; t<z ; t++){
    for(int u=t+1 ; u<z ; u++){
        if(b[t]==b[u]){
            for(int l = u; l < z; l++)
                {
                    b[l] = b[l + 1];
                }
                z--;
                u--;
            }
        }
    }
printf("\nArray2: ");
for(int e=0 ;e<z-1; e++){
    printf("%d, " ,b[e]);
}
printf("%d" ,b[z-1]);
int u[n+z] ; //union

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    u[i]=a[i];


}
for(int i=n ; i<(n+z)  ;i++){
    u[i]=b[i-n];
}
for(int i=0 ; i< n+z ; i++){ //remove repeated values from union
    for(int j=i+1 ; j< n+z ; j++){
        if(u[i]==u[j]){
            for(int l = j; l < z+n; l++)
                {
                    u[l] = u[l + 1];
                }
                n+z--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
printf("\nunion is ");
for(int i=0 ; i<(n+z-1) ;i++){
    printf("%d, ",u[i]);
}
printf("%d",u[n+z-1]);
//intersection............

int k = 0;
int I[k] ;   //intersection
for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++ ){
    for(int j=0 ; j<z ; j++ ){
        if(a[i]==b[j]){
            I[k]=a[i] ;
            k++;

          }
}
}
printf("\nintersection is ");
for(int i=0 ; i < k ;i++){
    printf("%d ",I[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Nina,I think he is doing that.

Comment: Add a `printf("\n");` at the end so the output will be flushed.

Comment: Note: `int I[n+z];` is way too large. The intersection can never be larger than the smallest of the two arrays.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought it was a 2D array.

Comment: @Omar Ashraf Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Paul anything less than `n or z` could result in `Array Index Out of Bounds` in case of this implementation. I believe OP's implementation is not intersection to be precise. It would also consider duplicate elements. Here, `{2,2} and {2}` would produce `{2,2}` as intersection set which is not correct and of course the resulting size is larger than the small array,

Comment: OK what I should do now I didn't understand you

Comment: @OmarAshraf As I wrote already provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem. Otherwise your question will be closed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  ok i provided a minimal complete program

Comment: @OmarAshraf Are arrays unsorted?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes unsorted

Answer (score 1):

This is the Code I've Written for finding an intersection

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a[10],b[10],c[10];
//A and B will accept input from user
//C will store intersected elements 
int main()
{
    int i,j,k=0;
    printf("\nEnter 5 elements in A[] : ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    printf("\nEnter 5 elements in B[] : ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(a[i]==b[j])
                c[k]=a[i],k++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<k;i++) printf("%d ",c[i]);
}




Input Given  
Enter 5 elements in A[] : 1 2 3 4 5

Enter 5 elements in B[] : 2 5 6 7 8

Output Produces
2 5
```